# Count how many times a letter appears in 2d array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, count

So I basically have an array that looks like this:

```
BG6001;1193;M;63;B+
BG6001;1124;M;41;C
BG6001;1121;F;FA;FA
BG6001;1143;M;26;FA
BG6001;1157;F;74;A
```

And what I've been trying to do is to count how many times the letter "M" appears in it, and add it into a counter

Any ideas?

What I have tried so far:

```
for (int i=0; i<name.length(); i++) { 
    if (name.charAt(i)=='M' ) counter++; 
} 
System.out.println("the string contains " + count + " times the letter M")
```

Comment: Have you tried researching? Please at least make some efforts before posting on StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi, yes I have, I've tried to implement other solutions into my project and it just won't work, excuse me though as I am a java newbie, this was my last attempt: `for (int i=0; i<name.length(); i++) {
        if (name.charAt(i)=='M' )
         counter++;
    }
    
    System.out.println("the string contains " +  count + " times the letter M");`

Comment: http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a homework question with no effort from the OP

Comment: But I've spent at least an hour trying to fix this.....

Comment: Can you show us how you're initializing the array? I'm a little confused about what it looks like. Is each row in your sample data supposed to be a separate array in the 2D array? Also, what is the "name" variable?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FASsSPE8 there you go

Comment: Just edit your question and post your code directly. Don't link to external code dumps.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use a foreach loop. Try implementing something like this:

```
int counter=0;
String[][] array = something;
for(String[] subArray : array)
    for(String string : subArray)
        if(string.toLowerCase().equals("m"))
            counter++;
//Counter has the value of the amount of 'm's in the array
```

Comment: I tried implementing it like this:

    `String[][] array = studentData;

for(String[] subArray : array)

    for(String string : subArray)

        if(string.toLowerCase().equals("M"))

            counter++;

System.out.println(counter);` but I get a runtime error (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException)

Comment: @mikefischer well, first of all compare string.toLowerCase with a lowercase "m" or use string.toUpperCase() and compare with "M" or trust the data to be consistent and compare string with "M". Concerning the NPE, could you please show what line of code the stacktrace refers to? could the problem be that studentData is a String[]? or can it possibly contain null?

Comment: it is indeed a string I believe, I had posted this before regarding studentData, what can I do about this? http://pastebin.com/kn0KcM7a
@7H3_H4CK3R

Comment: @mikefischer the importing code seems fine. what line of code causes the NullPointerException?

Comment: nevermind, managed to fix it, was on my end, thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

@mike fischer please check the below code whoich gives you the count of "M" in an Array.

```
public class Arraycount {
public static void main(String args[]){
String[] a=new String[5];
a[0]="BG6001;1193;M;63;B+";
a[1]="BG6001;1124;M;41;C";
a[2]="BG6001;1121;F;FA;FA";
a[3]="BG6001;1143;M;26;FA";
a[4]="BG6001;1157;F;74;A";
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<=a.length-1;i++){

    for(int j=0;j<=a[i].length()-1;j++){   
        char c=a[i].charAt(j);
        if(c=='M'){
            count++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Number of M present in an array is "+count);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very similar to 7H3_H4CK3R's answer with some variation. Specifically, if a particular letter (in this case, "M") could appear anywhere in the string, you can do the following (and I apologize for using C# rather than Java syntax here, I'm not sitting in front of a Java compiler, but hopefully the differences won't be too difficult to follow):

```
    private static int Count(string[][] data, char letterToFind)
    {
        int count = 0;

        // Loop over each array
        foreach (string[] array in data)
        {
            // Each array is a collection of strings
            foreach (string str in array)
            {
                // Loop through the characters in each string
                for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (str[i] == letterToFind)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
```

Alternatively, if you're looking for something where the entire string is "M" 7H3_H4CK3R's answer should do the trick.